# ChartJs Combo Chart / Line Chart Point Position to left not middle

Tags: chart.js

I am wondering how can I configure the position of line point to left as I have a two bar chart and I want to position on the top of the first bar chart

[image]

Hope you can help

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['dummy1', 'Jan 21st', 'Feb 21st', 'Mar 21st', 'Apr 21st', 'dummy2'],
    datasets: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'A',
        // the 1st and last value are placeholders and never get displayed on the chart
        data: [0, 10, 25, 18, 37, 0],
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'B',
        // the 1st and last value are placeholders and never get displayed on the chart
        data: [0, 10, 25, 18, 37, 0],
      },
      {
        type: 'line', 
        label: 'C',
        // the 1st and last value are placeholders and never get displayed on the chart
        // to get a straight line, the 1st and last values must match the same value as
        // the next/prev respectively
        data: [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#f00',
        borderDash: [5,4],
        lineTension: 0,
        steppedLine: true
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],  
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 'Jan 21st',
          max: 'Apr 21st',
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

To position the point in the first bar or position it to the left not middle